# Instantiating Java classes from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

If I have a class in Java

```
class Test {

}
```

How can I instantiate it from Groovy? I know how to bind a variable, so I could probably bind a factory object to create instances of my class. But I want to do

```
new Test()
```

From Groovy without using a factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. You have to import the class first:

```
import com.company.me.Test;
```

Now you can instantiate

```
new Test()
```